# How to display elements below each other?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have following:

```html
<div class="container-fluid" id="contact">
  <div class="row justify-content-center" align="center">
    <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div>
        <img src="icon-mail.png" style="padding-right:20px;">
      </div>
      <div>
        <h4>E-mail</h4>
        <p>gmail@gmail.sk</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div>
        <img src="icon-tel.png" style="padding-right:20px;">
      </div>
      <div>
        <h4>Call us</h4>
        <p>+00000000000</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is view with screen size >992:

[image]

This is view with screen <992:

[image]

How can I display elements below each other as is viewed in image2 ? I do not know why, but "display:block" is not working.

Comment: use media query and make it 100% wide

Comment: replace **'col-md-6'** class to **'col-lg-6'**

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap 5 there is an option named order. So in your question, You can add a class named order-md-2 to things that you want to shift down and order-md-1 to things that you want to shift up.

```html
<div class="container-fluid" id="contact">
  <div class="row justify-content-center" align="center">
    <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="order-md-1">
        <img src="icon-mail.png" style="padding-right:20px;">
      </div>
      <div>
        <h4>E-mail</h4>
        <p>gmail@gmail.sk</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="order-md-2">
        <img src="icon-tel.png" style="padding-right:20px;">
      </div>
      <div>
        <h4>Call us</h4>
        <p>+00000000000</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope my answer helps you

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<div class="row">
```

to create separate rows of content satisfying your needs.

I recommend to read about grid system in this article:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

```html
<div class="container-fluid" id="contact">
  <div class="row justify-content-center" align="center">
    <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div>
        <img src="icon-mail.png" style="padding-right:20px;">
      </div>
      <div>
        <h4>E-mail</h4>
        <p>gmail@gmail.sk</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-center" align="center">
    <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div>
        <img src="icon-tel.png" style="padding-right:20px;">
      </div>
      <div>
        <h4>Call us</h4>
        <p>+00000000000</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could simply use the flex-direction of the flexbox.

```html
<div class="container-fluid" id="contact">
  <div class="row justify-content-center" align="center">
    <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="order-md-1">
        <img src="icon-mail.png" style="padding-right:20px;">
      </div>
     <div class='contacts'>
      <div class='mail'>
        <h4>E-mail</h4>
        <p>gmail@gmail.sk</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="order-md-2">
        <img src="icon-tel.png" style="padding-right:20px;">
      </div>
      <div class='phone'>
        <h4>Call us</h4>
        <p>+00000000000</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
   </div>
```

Inside CSS:

```
.contacts {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

}

This should allow you to orient both of your div-containers to be underneath each other.